# Material UI 5: How to know when Collapse transition is finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, browser, material-ui

### My code

```
    <Collapse
      in={expanded}
      onTransitionEnd={() => console.log('finished')}
    >
        <div>foo</div>
    </Collapse>
```

### What's wrong

The callback (onTransitionEnd) is not called when the collapse animation is finished.

How should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also expected `addEndListener` ([Collapse API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/collapse/#props)) to trigger *after* the animation, which isn't the case. Similar to Sereyn's answer, this worked for me:

```
      <Collapse
        onEntered={() => console.log("expand animation done")}
        onExited={() => console.log("collapse animation done")}
        in={checked}
      >
        {icon}
      </Collapse>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a prop as `onTransitionEnd` neither in [API of Collapse](https://mui.com/api/collapse/#props) component, nor in the [Transition component](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition#Transition-props) from react-transition-group.

Depending on what exactly you want you can use either `addEndListener` prop which will fire at the end of both 'in' and 'out' animations, or `onExited` which will fire at the end of 'out' animation.

```
          <Collapse
            addEndListener={() => console.log("done")}
            onExited={() => console.log("finished")}
            in={checked}
          >
            {icon}
          </Collapse>
```

Comment: onExited is never fired and addEndListener is fired instantly, which is not what I expected

Comment: Click on the switch and check out the console log - https://codesandbox.io/s/simplecollapse-material-demo-forked-lgdtos?file=/demo.tsx

onExited does fire after the 'out' phase of animation.

Comment: Ah yes onExited does fire after the 'out' phase but I am still unable to know when the 'in' phase ends. I guess I could use setTimeout to have a callback function called after the amount of time the animation takes to play but it would be a hack.